# Does XStream support cyclic JSON graphs?

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, xstream

I have an object containing cyclic references. According to the XStream Json documentation, cyclic references are NOT supported, and one should therefore use [the NO_REFERENCES XStream mode](http://x-stream.github.io/graphs.html) when marshalling an object to Json:

> What limitations has XStream's JSON support?
>
> JSON represents a very simple data model for easy data transfer.
>   Especially it has no equivalent for XML attributes. Those are written
>   with a leading "@" character, but this is not always possible without
>   violating the syntax (e.g. for array types). Those may silently
>   dropped (and makes it therefore difficult to implement
>   deserialization). References are another issue in the serialized
>   object graph, since JSON has no possibility to express such a
>   construct. You should therefore always set the NO_REFERENCES mode of
>   XStream. Additionally you cannot use implicit collections, since the
>   properties in a JSON object must have unique names.

But I tried setting the mode to ID_REFERENCES and it appears as though the Object is marshalled *with* references, and the object can be unmarshalled properly. Is the XStream documentation simply outdated, or have I simply inadvertently created the object graph in such a way that I haven't hit any of the limitations?

Sorry, but I can't post my exact graph as an example as it contains application/domain-specific code and it might take some time to construct a 'clean' alternative.